# ASP .NET Core MVC - How to initialize an object property in a model class which is a result of many-to-many relationship?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

When I want to call a property of my object property Trip from TripApplicationUser model class its values are null. So I do not know how to initialize the Trip object to get its property values later on and to now have problem with indexing in database. I have pasted here the most important parts of code.

```
[Authorize]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Enroll(int id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        var currentTrip = await _context.Trip.FindAsync(id);
        var currentUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        var isAlreadyEnrolled = _context.TripApplicationUsers.Where(tu => tu.ApplicationUserId.Equals(currentUser.Id) && tu.TripId == id);
        var UserTrips = isAlreadyEnrolled.ToList();
        if (currentTrip.TripSeats > 0 && !UserTrips.Any())
        {
            ViewBag.process = "done";
            currentTrip.TripSeats--;
            _context.Update(currentTrip);

            var rowToSave = new TripApplicationUser
            {
                TripId = currentTrip.TripId,
                ApplicationUserId = currentUser.Id,
                Trip = currentTrip //HOW SHOULD I INITIALIZE IT ACTUALLY?
            };
            _context.Add(rowToSave);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        } else if (UserTrips.Any())
        {
            ViewBag.process = "already done";
        } else if(currentTrip.TripSeats <= 0)
        {
            ViewBag.process = "not done";
        }
        var UsersTrips = _context.TripApplicationUsers.Where(t => t.ApplicationUserId.Equals(currentUser.Id)).ToList();  
        return View(UsersTrips);
    }

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        [PersonalData]
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(MAX)")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [PersonalData]
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(MAX)")]
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        [PersonalData]
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(MAX)")]
        public string BirthDate { get; set; }

        public ICollection<TripApplicationUser> TripApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    }
public class Trip
    {
        public int TripId { get; set; }
        public string TripDate { get; set; }
        public int TripDuration { get; set; }
        public int TripLength { get; set; }
        public int TripSeats { get; set; }

        public int TrailId { get; set; }
        public Trail Trail { get; set; }


        public ICollection<TripApplicationUser> TripApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    }

public class TripApplicationUser
    {
        public int TripId { get; set; }
        public Trip Trip { get; set; }
        public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your Trip object to contain data from Navigational properties you have to include them in the request.

```
var currentTrip = await _context.Trip.Include(trip=> trip.TripApplicationUsers).FirstOrDefaultAsync(trip => trip.TripId == id);
```